# replace number in text to a random number within a range

Tags: text-processing

Right now I have text that looks something like

```
"xyz1"
zyx1
"http://xyz1"
zyx1
"xyz1"
zyx1
```

I need the `1` to be replaced by a random number within the range of `1-5` so that the output would look something like

```
"xyz3"
zyx2
"http://xyz1"
zyx5
"xyz4"
zyx1
```

`zyx` or `xyz` should be present before before the 1 to replace it with 1-5

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(zyx|xyz)\K1/1+int rand 5/ge' < file
```

Comment: Could you please describe particular parts of the command?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`s [rand()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html#index-Beebe_002c-Nelson-H_002eF_002e-1)
and [srand](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html#index-square-root) functions:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{print gensub(/(zyx|xyz)1/, "\\1"1 + int(rand() * 5), 1)}' file
```

Only the first occurrence of `zyx1` or `xyz1` is replaced in each line. If you want *all* possible occurrences replaced, change the last `1` to `"g"` (global).

**Note:** If the script is executed multiple times in the same second, it might produce the same result.

> If the argument x is omitted, as in ‘srand()’, then the current date and time of day are used for a seed. This is the way to get random numbers that are truly unpredictable.

If you don't want that, you could change change the random seed to a value of your choice like the nanoseconds portion of the current time if your `date` supports this:

```
seed=$(date '+%N')
awk -v s="$seed" 'BEGIN{srand(s)}{print gensub(/(zyx|xyz)1/, "\\1"1 + int(rand() * 5), 1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU **`awk`** calling **`shuf`** command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="shuf -i 1-5 -n1" }
     { cmd | getline num; close(cmd); sub("1", num) }1' file
```

The output:

```
"xyz3"
zyx4
"http://xyz2"
zyx5
"xyz1"
zyx2
```

Comment: Sorry could you change this so it searches for xyz before the 1

Comment: @Teddy291 change your description to clarify whether `xyz` or `zyx` or `yxz` are equivalents

Comment: Added `zyx` or `xyz` should be present before before the 1 to replace it with 1-5

Comment: @Teddy291, how about `yxz`, `yzx`, `zxy`, `x2y3z` ?